# Regarding the equivalence of two forms of family of lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Suppose we want to find the equation of line passing through the point of intersection of two straight lines $$a_1x+ b_1y+c_1=0$$
and $$a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$$ There are two ways of doing it.

First way would be to find the common point $(x_1,y_1)$ of this two lines obtained from solving this two equations and then writing the equation of any line passing through this point of intersection as $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$ where m is any quantity whatever.

The second way is, any point common to these two lines will satisfy *both* of these equations and hence it would satisfy the equation $$a_1x+b_1y+c_1+\lambda(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)=0$$ Thus whatever be the value of $\lambda$ this equation is always satisfied by the point of intersection of the two lines.

Now my question is in the first case $m$ is a parameter by varying which we get the family of straight lines passing through the point of intersection of given two lines and in the second case
$\lambda$is the parameter.

But this two family of lines are equivalent thus this two equations should be equivalent. But I have tried to prove the equivalence of this two equations but I have not succeed.

So, how can we show the equivalence of this two equations.

Comment: If the line equation fits $ax+by+c=0$, then you can try to prove $\det\left[\begin{matrix}a_1&b_1&c_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2\\a&b&c\end{matrix}\right]=0$.

Comment: @auntyellow That wouldn't prove the equivalence. However there is no such equivalence as pointed out in answer. But I will try to reduce the two parameter version in both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are incomplete.

Let $a_1=b_1=b_2=1$ and $a_2=0=c_1=c_2$ so that we are dealing with lines $x+y=0$ and $y=0$ and $(0,0)$ is the intersection.

Equation $y=mx$ does not provide the line $x=0$.

Equation $x+y+\lambda y=0$ does not provide the line $y=0$.

This also shows that there is no equivalence because the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$ are distinct.

Comment: So this means that both the equations cannot represent all the equations passing through the point of intersection. Also, is there any equation which represents all the lines passing through the point of intersection

Comment: I think you cannot escape from using $2$ parameters. E.g. $a(y-y_1)=b(x-x_2)$.

Comment: Typo discovered in former comment. I meant: $a(y-y_1)=b(x-x_1)$. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to drhab's answer, the first way $y−y_1=m(x−x_1)$ is incomplete for all lines passing through $(x_1,y_1)$ (here we don't consider the degenerated case that the two lines $a_1x+b_1y+c_1=0$ and $a_2x+b_2y+c_2=0$ are parallel) . However, as drhab also commented, we can change the form as:

$$n(y−y_1)=m(x−x_1)\quad\text{(1)}$$

Analogously, we can change the second way as:

$$\kappa(a_1x+b_1y+c_1)+\lambda(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)=0\quad\text{(2)}$$

In fact, these two ways are equivalent because both (1) and (2) can be represented as:

$$ax+by+c=0\quad\text{(3)}$$

In the first way:

$$\begin{cases}a=m\\b=-n\\c=ny_1-mx_1=n\dfrac{\det\left[\begin{matrix}c_1&a_1\\c_2&a_2\end{matrix}\right]}{\det\left[\begin{matrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\end{matrix}\right]}-m\dfrac{\det\left[\begin{matrix}b_1&c_1\\b_2&c_2\end{matrix}\right]}{\det\left[\begin{matrix}a_1&b_1\\a_2&b_2\end{matrix}\right]}\end{cases}\quad\text{(1')}$$

In the second way:

$$\begin{cases}a={\kappa}a_1+{\lambda}a_2\\b={\kappa}b_1+{\lambda}b_2\\c={\kappa}c_1+{\lambda}c_2\end{cases}\quad\text{(2')}$$

Both (1') and (2') can be represented as:

$$\det\left[\begin{matrix}a_1&b_1&c_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2\\a&b&c\end{matrix}\right]=0\quad\text{(3')}$$